# "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable" problem with charAt

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
private String kNow(String state, String guess) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (guess.equals(word.charAt(i))) {
                state.charAt(i) = word.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        return state;
    }
```

state.charAt(i) part points the problem in the title. 
How can I solve the problem, if my approach is not completely wrong.

Comment: What is `word`? What do you want the method to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because `charAt(int x)` is a method of the `String` class - namely it is a function, and you can't assign a function a value in Java.

If you want to loop through a string character by character, I might be tempted to do this:

```
Char[] GuessAsChar = guess.toCharArray();
```

Then operate on GuessAsChar instead. There are, depending on your needs, possibly better (as in neater) ways to approach searching for character equivalence in strings.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly sure what the intention is for `guess.equals(word.charAt(i))` as that statement will always evaluate to false since a `String` never can equal a `char`, but you want to convert your `String` to a `StringBuilder`

```
private String kNow(String state, String guess) {
    final StringBuilder mutable = new StringBuilder(state);
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (guess.equals(word.charAt(i))) {
            mutable.setCharAt(i, word.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return mutable.toString();
}
```

Comment: +1 For pointing out that the if statement always fails. i also added this to my anser (8 seconds before you :-P ) but it is such an important point that I think you should be upvoted too.

Comment: This wouldn't compile. There is no `word` declared.

Comment: I imagine `word` is a field in the declaring class.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) in Java. This means that you cannot change a string object once you have created it. You can however create a new string and then reassign it to the variable.

```
state = state.substring(0, i) + word.charAt(i) + state.substring(i + 1);
```

However in this situation I think it would be better to use a mutable type for `state` such as a character array (`char[]`). This allows you to modify individual characters directly.

A second problem with your code is that `guess` should presumably be a char, not a string. Currently your `if` statement will always return false because an object of type  `string` will never be equal to an object of type `char`.

Answer (score 3):

Strings in Java are immutable: you can't change string after it's created. It might be better to use `byte[]` or `char[]` or collection for `state`.